# How to restore full mysql (dir)

Tags: mysql, backup, innodb, restore

My problem is: I'm saved the /var/www/virtual and the /var/lib/mysql directories. And after reinstall OS I set up the MySQL and when restored these two directories i'm got error in mysql server. So MySQL server don't want to start up.
So what way can i restore the mysql database directory?
The MySQL server don't start after I copy the ibdata1 file.

Comment: Well, are we meant to _guess_ what error mysql throws? post it here!

Comment: If you try to restore your databases by restoring these files, it will not work for most engine types. AFAIK only MyISAM supported this hacky kind od backing up data.